# Configuring Infinispan as remote second level cache for Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, infinispan, distributed-caching

As per Infinispan documentation the following settings make up setting infinispan as a L2 Cache provider for Entities

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />   
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />  
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory"/>
```

Then further one can annotate Entities with @javax.persistence.Cacheable  to make them candidate for L2 cache.

My question is how to make this a remote cache ?

Comment: any help from [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/infinispan-remote-cache)

Comment: @ankur-singhal thx but that link is a general inifinispan remote configuration. Nothing explains how RemoteCacheManager comes into play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infinispan 2LC implementation for remote cache does not exist. You could maybe configure the embedded caches used for Infinispan 2LC with a remote cache store which talks to one or multiple Infinispan Servers. Please note that this has not been tested and there's no guarantees that it'll work as expected due to the peculiarities and the optimizations done by the embedded Infinispan 2LC implementation.

Comment: Just to confirm the option is provide alternative for infinispan-config.xml that it uses by default ? Also wondering if you mind sharing the peculiarities/optimization in embedded cache manager which is DefaultCacheManager.

Comment: Yeah, you'd need a separate configuration. You can check the code in Github (https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-infinispan) but we use a lot of Flags in order to tweak different caching operations to make them as optimal as we can. Some of these optimisations can be applied to remote caches but not all.